# Python3 Lists in Lists recursion

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion

So I'm trying to count how many times a certain thing (for example,"X") comes up in a list without using for loops. So I tried two things:

ex: b = [["X",2,4],[2,3,1],["X","X",1]] and countX should return => 3

first time I tried this:

```
def countX(b):
    if b == []:
        return 0
    elif b[0] == []:
        return countX(b[1:])
    elif b[0][0] == "X":
        return countX(b[0][1:]) + 1
    else:
        return countX(b[0][1:])
```

but I think im missing a case? If someone knows what went wrong here please explain :)

The second method I tried to use count like this:

```
def countX(b, posn):
    if posn == len(b):
        return 0
    else:
        return countX(b, pos+1) + b(pos).count("X")
```

for this method I would enter in posn as 0
but I'm also getting an error that I don't understand... it says 'list' object not callable. What does that mean?

I don't really want a simpler method to solve this problem I just want to know why the two methods I have tried don't work and how I might go about fixing them.

Thanks in advance!

~edit: and without importing anything~

Comment: `b(pos)` this should be `b[pos]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method, change `b(pos)` to `b[pos]`, use `[]` to get list item:

```
>>> b = [["X",2,4],[2,3,1],["X","X",1]] 
>>> def count_X(b, pos):
...     if pos == len(b):
...         return 0
...     else:
...         return count_X(b, pos+1) + b[pos].count('X')
... 
>>> count_X(b,0)
3
>>>
```

Comment: Oh ok that does fix the 2nd method and makes sense! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to make sure `b` is a list before you iterate through it or try to access its elements with `b[0]` or `b[1:]`.

Try this for the 1st method:

```
import collections

def count_X(b):
    if b == "X":
        return 1
    if isinstance(b, collections.Iterable):
        return sum(count_X(elem) for elem in b)
    else:
        return 0
```

If you are sure you only deal with lists, you can replace `collections.Iterable` with `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But I'm trying to figure out a method that doesn't require any importing

Comment: as I said, you can use simple `list` instead for your case. The `import collections` is just to make it more general.

Comment: Oh I see I wasn't 100% what you meant since I didn't know what collections did. I'll try out your method! Thanks for an alternative.

Comment: `collections.Iterable` is basically a generic class containing all iterable container objects like lists, tuples, dicts, sets etc... This line basically just checks whether `b` is a list. You could also do this with `if type(b) == list`.

Answer (score 1):

In your first program, ask yourself what happens when b is a list and it's first element is 'X'. (Hint: It will be an IndexError)

Other answers avoid explicit loops, but use them behind the scene nonetheless. So,if you are really determined to avoid any loop....

```
def func(li):
    ans=0
    if type(li) is list and len(li):
        ans+=func(li[0])
        ans+=func(li[1:])
    elif li=='X':
        return 1
    return ans
```

When run:

```
>>> b=[[23,'X',['X','jh',['as','X']],['X']],'X','S']
>>> func(b)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Hihi.  In the first method if b[0][0] == "X" you are then only recursing on the first row b[0].  You need to recurse on the first row without the first column (as you do) plus the other rows (i.e. b[1:]), or delete the b[0][0] as in ....

```
def count_X(b, r, c):
    if r == len(b):
        return 0
    if c == len(b[r]):
        return count_X(b, r+1, 0)

    count = count_X(b, r, c+1)
    if b[r][c] == "X":
        count += 1

return count
```

In the second method you never add 1 if there is an X.  You are getting the error because b(pos) is invalid - that's function call syntax applied to a list.  I would suggest using a 2 dimensional pos to keep track of where you are in terms of rows and columns ...

```
def count_X(b, r, c):
    if r == len(b):
        return 0
    if c == len(b[r]):
        return count_X(b, r+1, 0)

    count = count_X(b, r, c+1)
    if b[r][c] == "X":
        count += 1

return count
```